# ASP.NET: .NET Framework/Standard/Core DLL collisions, caused by Nuget. "You must add a reference to assembly System.Runtime..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget

We have an ASP.NET .NET Framework 4.7.2 project.  Unfortunately, we want to reference newer Nugets, which inevitably drag in .NET Standard, or worse yet, Core.  Every time we want to include a new Nuget, it's like playing Russian roulette with the project.  Most of the time, it will result in some version of:

`You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Today, it happened during compilation of a view, after referencing a .NET Standard project.

As there are multiple System.Runtime DLLs, from .NET Framework, Standard, or Core, and Visual Studio can't tell which one to put in the bin folder.  Usually it defaults on Framework from the GAC.

**Failed Solution: `<dependentAssembly>`**

We have tried all sorts of things, primarily `<dependentAssembly>` in our web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

However this leads to the project blowing up at run-time, during our dependency injection setup, asking for multiple versions of System.Runtime at the same time:

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

and

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

**Failed Hacky Solution: `<dependentAssembly>` and Copying DLL on Post-Build**

We'd use the above, but then copied the System.Runtime DLL we hand-chose to the bin folder on post build.  A terrible solution, which worked great locally, but blew up on production, causing all sorts of DLLs not to be found.

**Increasingly Difficult Solution: Avoid .NET Standard and Core Entirely**

We've been struggling with this for a week, and in other projects, for months.  Each time we run into it, it takes days to solve.  The only clear-cut solution we've found is to simply avoid Nugets that require .NET Standard or Core.  But that is getting harder and harder everyday.

**Unfeasible Solution: PackageReference, or upgrade to .NET Core**

Supposedly, the latest way to reference packages, PackageReference, usually solves this problem.  But ASP.NET on .NET Framework 4.7.2 (still actively supported by Microsoft) does not support this, because ASP.NET Nuget packages oftentimes have scripts that get executed upon installation, which isn't supported by PackageReference.  Otherwise, we need to upgrade our website to .NET Core; we've run the analyzer, and it says we'd have to rewrite 15% of the site, which is just not acceptable at this time.

**Failed Solution: Slowly Move Everything Out of the .NET Framework 4.7.2 ASP.NET Project**

We thought we'd be crafty, and start converting our libraries to .NET Standard. 
 New features and slowly old features, would be put in the .NET Standard libraries, which uses PackageReference, hopefully avoiding the DLL Hell.  About a day into this experiment, we unfortunately were back to square one, because the ASP.NET project which is still on .NET Framework 4.7.2 is the root of the whole solution.  In fact, strangely enough, we tried to undo the latest change that seemingly caused the collision, and it is now seemingly permanent, despite cleaning and rebuilding.  It honestly seems like luck of the draw whether it'll work or not.  Luck seemed to factor in another solution with a similar problem, where one developer's machine would have it working, but another wouldn't, or a local deploy would work, but a production deploy would not.

**Failed Solution: RestoreProjectStyle**

Surely we couldn't be alone.  It took a long time to find a way to Google the problem, but we finally did find other people with the same problem.  This is probably the best example: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/747

We tried adding `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to our ASP.NET project, but that actually seemed to make things worse, making the System.Runtime issue permanent, even upon reverting the change, cleaning,

**Failed Solution: Side-by-side via `Assembly.Load`**

We tried `Assembly systemRuntime = Assembly.Load("System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");` in an attempt to load the two System.Runtimes side-by-side, but it had no impact.  Upon loading a view, it still says:

`CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

Is there a way to reference assemblies for view-time compiling?

**Conclusion**

I've been stuck on the .NET Framework world for a long time, so Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Standard/Core are fairly new to me.  But even with discussions with veterans, they seemed to say that avoiding the problem is the best solution.

Otherwise, we're getting into super hacky solutions, like manually loading DLLs on initialization (probably what we'll try next).

Comment: I would update to .NET Core sooner rather than later. .NET Framework is on its way out the door and you're only going to run into more and more problems like this as the world moves on to Core

Comment: Just wondering which packages cause this since to me Visual Studio will clearly say if the package supports a specific framework version, or .NET Standard (which shouldn’t be an issue by itself since 4.7.1 supports .NET Standard 2.0) etc. So how do packages get in there which aren’t supported?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Great question.  What started the most recent attempt for us to support .NET Standard was the desire to make events on our website trigger a message on a Discord text channel.  Discord.Net states it supports .NET Framework 4.6, .NET Standard 1.3 and .NET Standard 2.0.  Which you would thin would not cause any issues.

Comment: For us, adding just about any Nuget package has a very high likelihood of causing System.Runtime not found errors. Trust me, we're losing our minds over here too. Like, this is a show-stopper of a problem.  We can't fathom that ASP.NET 4.7.1, still an officially supported platform by Microsoft, is so delicate.  There has to be a common solution we're just not aware of out there...

Comment: @Zoop That does sound like there’s something wrong with the package. Have to have a look at that one myself. For me VS has very helpfully always said “sorry, package doesn’t support your platform” so far but I have mostly been using the most popular packages which may have better handled versioning

Comment: Last week, we had a similar problem upgrading from version 4.0.0 of Tweetinvi to 4.0.1.  We never thought such a minor version upgrade could be so catastrophic.

Comment: If you upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.2, then many pains go away themselves, https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET Keep in mind that .NET Standard was created in a rush, so it took very long for the whole ecosystem to catch up with it.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.7.1 only has partial support for .NET standard 2.0. The first .NET framework with full .NET Standard 2.0 support is 4.7.2 as this one doesn’t need additional runtime dependencies which seems to be the issue you are facing. So you should update to this version.

Comment: I apologize, we are on 4.7.2.  I have updated the original post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have seen System.Runtime missing in many places, at this current moment, it was blowing up when loading a view.

Little did I know, apparently the view engine doesn't necessarily use the same assemblies as the main project!  See my answer in another post for how to add assemblies to the view engine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57350759/2589506